# What is the correct mask to use with 224.0.0.0?

Tags: ipv4, ip, subnet, multicast, ip-address

What is the best mask to use to allow computers to use the multicast IP address 224.0.0.0?

I've only seen IP addresses using the lower 8 bits, in my case I just see 22 and 251.

So my firewall uses an entry as follow:

```
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p udp -m udp -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Now I have found other definitions that use a mask as small as 4 or 5 for the 224.0.0.0 address. What is the right mask according to the use of the 224.0.0.0 address scope definition?

Comment: As Ron alludes, the correct answer is "/4" (224.0.0.0-239.255.255.255) That is the size of the multicast block.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use any addresses from 224.0.0.0 (except for multicast) through 255.255.255.254, and 255.255.255.255 is a Limited Broadcast address.

Multicast addresses are 224.0.0.0/4.  Masks are not used in multicast; you subscribe, individually, to multicast groups.

Reserved addresses are 240.0.0.0/4.  While named "[Class E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network)" in the old class routing scheme, their use is undefined (they can't be used as source or destination addresses, and they can't be forwarded, per [RFC 6980](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6890)).